# A better way to handle a simple markup to html converter in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

Yes I know there are already classes/packages/systems out there that do this for me, but I've got some requirements and design choices that preclude me from using them. So given that I've decided to implement my own simple markup is there a better way to handle headers than I'm currently doing?

```
// Basic markup, based on markdown
public static function MarkupToHtml($text) {
    $text = Util::cleanup($text);
    $text = preg_replace('/^[ ]+$/m', '', $text);

    // Add a newline after headers
    // so paragraphs work properly. Should figure out regex so it doesn't
    // add an extra \n if its not needed
    $text = preg_replace('{(^|\n)([=]+)(.*?)(\n)}', "$0\n", $text);

    // Paragraphs
    // Ignore header lines
    $text = preg_replace('{(\n\n|^)([^=])(.|\n)*?(?=\n\n|$)}', '<p>$0</p>', $text);

    // Headers
    // This works, but is there a cleaner way to go about it
    preg_match_all ("/(^|\n)([=]+)(.*?)(\n)/", $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches as $val) {
        $num = intval(strlen($val[2])) + 2;
        if ($num > 5) {
            $num = 5;
        }
        $text = str_replace($val[0], "<h" . $num . ">" . $val[3] . "</h" . $num .">", $text);
    }

    // Bold
    $text = preg_replace('{([*])(.*?)([*])}', '<strong>$2</strong>', $text);

    // Italic
    $text = preg_replace('{([_])(.*?)([_])}', '<em>$2</em>', $text);

    // mono
    $text = preg_replace('{([`])(.*?)([`])}', "<span style='font-family:monospace;'>$2</span>", $text);


    return $text;
}
```

Comment: The better way is to use existing library

Comment: And as explained in the very first sentence of the question, thats not an option. Thanks for the pointless comment.

Comment: If it works, don't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use preg_match_callback:

```
$line = preg_replace_callback(
        '/(^|\n)([=]+)(.*?)(\n)/',
        create_function(
            '$matches',
            '$num = min(intval(strlen($matches[2])) + 2,5);' .
            'return "<h" . $num . ">" . $matches[3] . "</h" . $num .">";'
        ),
        $line
    );
```